# Proposed FAQ "What kind of questions can I ask here?" entry

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The In the spirit of how other SE communities expanded on their current FAQ entry of ["What kind of questions can I ask here?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), I propose that ours read as follows:

> This site is for *academics* of all levels—from aspiring graduate and professional students to senior researchers—as well as *anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent* fields. If you have a question about...
>
> - Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
> - Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
> - Inner workings of research departments
> - Requirements and expectations of academicians
>
> ... then you're in the right place!
>
> To help people answer your question, please recognize that this forum is frequented by academicians from across the globe, from across diverse fields research, and with a wide range of experience, from first-year graduate student to tenured professor. State your question as much context as you can to help ensure that you'll receive a directed, relevant answer.

Comment: eykanal: Regarding your flag. The \[faq\] tag is used to mark the most frequently asked and answered questions on Meta (i.e. it comprises the 'faq'). It is not used to mark discussions *about* the faq.

Comment: @RobertCartaino - Huh. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Enrolled in higher education" means undergraduate students as well. So I think you'd want to say

> This site is for *academics* of all levels—from aspiring graduate and professional students to senior researchers—as well as *anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent* fields.

This allows us to cover the full range of people, while making clear that we're not really addressing undergraduate admissions.

Comment: Good clarification. I'll take issue with one part: "post-graduate students", on first blush, reads as "post-doctorates". Unless you specifically mean something by "post-graduate", I think the term "graduate students" would be more clear.

Comment: I mean by "postgraduate" anybody who's beyond their respective undergraduate degrees. This would include MD-PhD students, and other disciplines that might not fall under the traditional graduate student rubric.

Comment: how about "post-undergraduate" then? Or, if the term "post-graduate" is the correct one and I'm just unfamiliar with it, let me know, as well.

Comment: "Postgraduate" means "after the first degree," so basically exactly the definition we want. Perhaps we point them to [this definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/postgraduate) as part of the FAQ.

Comment: I agree that the term "post-graduate" or "post-undergraduate" can be confusing, so I'd be in favor of "This site is for academics (from graduate-students to full professors and senior researchers), and anyone interested in research-related or research-adjacents fields"

Comment: @CharlesMorisset - I like your idea, and I changed the answer based on the comment. What do you (and aeismail) think?

Comment: I think "aspiring undergraduates" is exactly the group that should  _not_ be covered!

Comment: I agree with aeismail, I understand "aspiring undergraduates" as those who are not yet undergrad, and who want to be, which is not really the focus of this site. But if you put "aspiring graduate students", then I think it's much better :)

Comment: The sooner we get the expanded faq in place, the better its gonna be - there are some rogue users who really need to read it!