# Can the predefined off topic reason for closing please link to the on topics description?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I'm not sure who is actually responsible for the 'reasons for closing' choices when voting to close so I don't know how to get it edited. One of the options is that it is off topic. But that reason does not actually link to https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, the only link is to a meta discussion about undergraduate being within scope in certain situations. As well as voting to close, I left a comment that the content of research is off topic and included the link, but that sort of thing should happen automatically.

Comment: Related: [New audience-specific texts for our custom close reasons](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/new-audience-specific-texts-for-our-custom-close-reasons).

Answer (score 5):

**This seems like a good idea to me.** Let's wait a little while to make sure there is a consensus, and then we'll make the change.

To be clear, the current close reason in question in this: [image: close reason] We can turn "outside our community's scope" into a hyperlink to the help center.

Note, this would only change what the close-voter sees when they are voting to close. The question-asker is already provided with a post notice that includes a link to the document in question:
[image: blah]

Higher-rep users are given a different close notice, but this also includes the link: [image]

**Edit 22 July 2020:** This is done.

Comment: If I had realised the OP gets a link to the relevant help once there are enough votes, then I wouldn't have left the comment on the question that triggered me to ask about this. But I would still find it useful to have the link in the vote closing text because I had to hunt it down to check the wording of the 'content of research' bit.

Comment: *This will put us four characters over the limit* – Not necessarily. `[clearly outside our community’s scope](/help/on-topic)` should work and that’s within the character limit.

Comment: I had no idea you could reference "local paths" like that! Awesome.