# Comment templates

Tags: discussion

I know some Stacks have comment templates to leave when a question or an answer has a problem. For example, [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) has [this Meta question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/templates-for-leaving-comments) with comment templates for several common situations. I've tried searching for something similar here but wasn't able to find it. Does Academia have something like this, and if not, should something be created?

I think the advantage would be that the comments will be uniformly informative with possibly links to relevant answers. It's important to note that at some point users at IPS were annoyed by the canned comments only, so personalization should still be applied, but I think this would make sense, and also for new users it could be a useful guide in formulating comments on problematic questions/answers.

Especially in combination with something like [this user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) this can save time when reviewing questions.

Answer (score 2):

What common situations do you have in mind for this site? I'm generally not a fan of that type of canned comments. I have a few canned comments that I use for moderation purposes, when e.g. I delete non-answers from new users, but apart from this I prefer to write specific comments when needed.

Personal preferences aside, for what concerns close reasons specifically, take into account that there are now audience-specific texts and that Wrzlprmft did a great job in preparing [guidance to post owners](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4710/20058) with links to the relevant FAQs.

For other stuff, moderators can also add post notices (you may have seen a few of them here and there):

[image]

Therefore, overall, I don't think we need comment templates.

Comment: This was mainly because I saw this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158530/what-should-i-do-when-i-have-a-bad-programming-teacher 
We've had questions before from high-school students that are not really about academia. I spent some time looking for the relevant meta question, and commented that it didn't fit the scope. Not too much work, but I was wondering if there was something in place that I wasn't able to find. I did not know Wrzlprmft's post by the way, thanks for that one.