# Why is "Opinion-based" listed separately within the Close vote dialog, instead of under "A community-specific reason"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close, user-interface

Why is "Opinion-based" listed as a close reason in its own right in the Close vote dialog, and not instead found under "A community-specific reason" (along with other, similar reasons like "strongly depends on individual factors")?

Aren't opinion-based questions not also not in line with Academia SE's guidelines? At least for me, it would make much more sense to put it under the umbrella "community-specific reason".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *opinion-based* closing reason is part of the network-wide closing reasons, and these cannot be customised at site level. That is, it’s a closing reason that can be found in any site of the network. The network-wide closing reasons were decided by the Stack Exchange staff.

The custom close reasons are those that can be customised by each site and they are shown in a separate menu. You can read the discussion about our current custom close reasons [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4710/20058).