# Who wrote the Help Center claim that we are a forum, and why?

Tags: discussion, help-center

In the [Help Center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there's a sentence that claims we are a forum:

> To help people answer your question, please recognize that this forum is frequented by academicians from across the globe

Who wrote this, and why is it there? (I'm not asking whether it should be changed, because of course it should be - [this site is not, in the usual web sense, a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/164022).)

Comment: The line in question has been there since [the begining](http://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/10435/1) and was added by an SE community moderator. That said, there is no reason for us not to change it. It would be great if answers could provide some suggested replacement text like this [question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/if-your-question-is-not-about-proposed-change-to-help-center-text).

Comment: Since there has been no disagreement with my proposed replacement text, I have now updated the help center.

Answer (score 8):

It was previously discussed on meta [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/proposed-faq-what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here-entry). The text was placed in the help center by a StackExchange community manager since there were no temporary moderators here to do it yet, but it originated from the community via meta.

I propose the following replacement text for that paragraph:

> [Academic customs and procedures vary greatly](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1212/11365) across countries, universities, fields, subfields, workgroups and so on. Please state your question with as much context as you can to help ensure that you'll receive a directed, relevant answer.

Comment: Nice find. I looked and was not able to dig out that discussion question.